# Как задать range() в цикле for (Django)

Tags: python, django

Имеется таблица рейтинга.

```
  <tbody>
    {% for user in users %}
<tr>
  <td>Место</td>
  <td>{{ user.username}}</td>
  <td>{{ user.score }}</td>
</tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Но как указать какое у него место, то есть как сделать range(), скажем от 1 до 10.
Видел такой способ, но он не работает.

```
{% for i in range(5, 10) %}
{{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Выдает ошибку "'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for i in range(5, 10)"

Comment: range(start, stop, step)  |   range(1,10,1)

Comment: 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for i in range(1, 10, 1)

Answer (score 0):

Пишу тут, потому что не могу писать комментарии.
Насколько я знаю такой возможности нет или я не нашел способ сделать это, но вы можете в python делать всю логику, которую хотите, а в шаблоне просто выводить её

Comment: Я нашел ответ, гляньте.

Answer (score 0):

На форуме нашел [ответ](https://overcoder.net/q/51942/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-loopcounter-%D0%B2-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-python-jinja). Я понял, что я не правильно вопрос задал.

```
  <tbody>
    {% for user in users %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.username}}</td>
  <td>{{ user.score }}</td>
</tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Таким образом у меня выводится range(1, len(users) + 1)